# Remove Layer preview in Geoserver

Tags: geoserver

I'm using Geoserver 2.1.1, Is there way to remove the Layer preview?, actually I'm only using the gmaps web services, I want to remove the KML preview or at least add some sort of authentication.

Comment: why would you want to do that? Your data will still be available to all.

Comment: yes but only as tile images, not as plain text coordinates / values

Comment: They'll always be able to derive the coordinates by adding the tiles to openlayers or something else (qgis).

Comment: make sure you turn off WFS as well then :-)

Comment: I only have WMS turned on, but all the previews are available even without authentication, my only answer by now is hiding the server behind a proxy. Or a more radical solution is not using geoserver at all, I've already replicated the web services and the geocache behavior with a python-mapnik script. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go into the geoserver/WEB-INF/lib folder and locate the demo jar, remove it, restart GeoServer. All previews will be gone

Comment: Hi,
if I remove the web-demo.jar from geoserver 2.3.0, it doesn't start after reloading. Is there any other way to remove layer preview?